# Quotes within HERE document in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, interpolation

G'day,

I'm getting syntax errors when working with a shell script like the following:

```
ssh root@mm-$user-vm-lenny <<EOF

check_dbtag=`grep "<<include /home/$user/cvs/dbtag.conf>>" /etc/dbtag.conf`

if [ "$check_dbtag" == "" ]
then
    echo '<<include /home/$user/cvs/dbtag.conf>>' >> /etc/dbtag.conf
fi 
EOF
```

The error I'm getting is

```
-bash: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
-bash: line 21: 'check_dbtag=<<include /home/thomasw/cvs/dbtag.conf>>'
```

However, I don't get it anymore if I change the line

```
check_dbtag=`grep "<<include /home/$user/cvs/dbtag.conf>>" /etc/dbtag.conf`
```

to

```
check_dbtag=`grep '<<include /home/$user/cvs/dbtag.conf>>' /etc/dbtag.conf`
```

however `$user` doesn't interpolate anymore.

How can I correctly interpolate the variable without any errors?

Comment: No, you did _not_ find a bug, pre-tags are not code, they do not disable interpretation of the special characters. If you want that, indent by four spaces or use code-tags. I fixed it for you...

Comment: I thought ``<pre>`` tags automatically inserted ``<pre><code>`` for this editor -- I've never used ``<code>`` tags before. TIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back tick is evaluated on your machine, not the target machine. I'd do it like this:

```
check_dbtag=\$(grep "<<include /home/$user/cvs/dbtag.conf>>" /etc/dbtag.conf)
```

Depending on whether you want the `$user` to be evaluated on the host or target machine, you might want to escape `$` with `\$` as well.

You will need to escape `$check_dbtag` to `\$check_dbtag` since you want *that* to be evaluated on your target machine.